# Java Group by functionality

Tags: java, list, grouping

Let's say I have a Java class 'Academics' with the following variables: SchoolId, BatchId, SectionID, studentID, SubjectID, Marks, Marks2

Then I have a list of this class with a number of values. (List)

Now I want find the SUM of Marks and Marks2 by grouping this in combinations of different columns, i.e
I want to group it by:

1. SchoolId + BatchId + SectionID
2. SchoolId + BatchId + SectionID + studentID
3. SchoolId + BatchId + SectionID + studentID + SubjectID

This is easily attainable through SQL, but what is the best way of grouping in Java?

Comment: Side note: naming conventions state that Java variables should start with a lower case letter, e.g. `schoolId` instead of `SchoolId`.

Comment: `what is the best way of grouping in Java`- I'd say there is no single best way, which approach to choose would depend on what you actually need. Btw, you can't easily compare SQL and Java, so don't expect Java solutions to look as compact as SQL solutions.

Comment: Yes, this is just a random example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code recipe**

1. Define 3 different comparators for your `Academics` class; one for each
   of the specifics you mentioned. i.e. comparator `SchoolBatchSection`
   will consider two objects of `Academics` equal only if their schoolId,
   batchId and sectionId are equal. Similarly define comparators
   `SchoolBatchSectionStudent` and `SchoolBatchSectionStudentSubject`.
2. Define 3 additional lists in addition to your original list for each
   of your specifics and fill them with distinct values of each
   specific. i.e. `list1` will contain only the distinct values in your
   original list with equality being seen from the eyes of
   `SchoolBatchSection`. `list2` will contain distinct elements w.r.t.
   `SchoolBatchSectionStudent` and `list3` w.r.t.
   `SchoolBatchSectionStudentSubject`.
3. Define 3 functions (or one higher order function if you can pass
   first class functions as parameters to it) that iterate through the original
   list and sum up the marks as per the required criterion.
4. Iterate through the three lists and for each distinct values, call up the suitable function you defined and print the sum returned by it.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this simple ready to run example:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

         class Academics {

            String schoolID, sectionID, studentID;

            public Academics(String schoolID, String sectionID, String studentID) {
                this.schoolID = schoolID;
                this.sectionID = sectionID;
                this.studentID = studentID;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                builder.append("Academics [schoolID=");
                builder.append(schoolID);
                builder.append(", sectionID=");
                builder.append(sectionID);
                builder.append(", studentID=");
                builder.append(studentID);
                builder.append("]");
                return builder.toString();
            }

        }
        List<Academics> academics = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
                new Academics("A", "A1", "1"),
                new Academics("B", "A2", "2"),
                new Academics("A", "A4", "3"),
                new Academics("C", "A1", "4"),
                new Academics("D", "A1", "5"),
                new Academics("C", "A6", "6"),
                new Academics("A", "A2", "7"),
                new Academics("B", "A2", "8")
        ));


        List<Comparator<Academics>> columnComparators = new ArrayList<>();

        // Group By: schoolID + sectionID + studentID
        columnComparators.add(new Comparator<Academics>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Academics a, Academics b) {

                int bySchoolId = a.schoolID.compareTo(b.schoolID);

                if(bySchoolId == 0){ // equal

                    int bySectionID = a.sectionID.compareTo(b.sectionID);

                    if(bySectionID == 0){// equal
                        return a.studentID.compareTo(b.studentID);
                    }
                    return bySectionID;
                }

                return bySchoolId;
            }
        });

        //... add more Comparators

        Collections.sort(academics, columnComparators.get(0)); // clickedColumn.getIndex()

        for (Academics a : academics) {
            System.out.println(a);
        }

    }
```

perhaps you need something like this.